# Prevent user from entering specific characters into DataWindow column

Tags: powerbuilder

I need to throw a message box whenever a user enters specific characters(cents sign, '', "" and (parenthesis)) into the DataWindow column in PowerBuilder.

I tried :

ls_text = dw_1.getitemstring(1, 'column')

but don't know how to parse the entered text (ls_text) and search for those characters mentioned above.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fortunatelly there are many choices to do this. To find a particular string in an another string you can use the following functions:

- [`Pos()`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc37781.1200/html/psref/BFCDBACJ.htm)
- [`LastPos()`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc37781.1200/html/psref/BFCDBACJ.htm)

Keep in mind, that the functions above are CASE SENSITIVE.
For example if you would like to find the first "comma" in a string:

```
integer li_ret

li_ret = Pos("Luke, I am your father :)", ",") // li_ret will be 5
If( li_ret > 0 )then
    Messagebox("Warning", "I'm Darth Vader!")
end if
```

If you need more, and you would like to search for "regular expression", you can use:

- `Match()`

You have also many possibilities to do this check:

- `ItemChanged` event
- `EditChanged` event
- Datawindow's Validation expression and Validation message

In the `ItemChanged` event you have the possibility to reject the value if it is necessary!

I hope this help! Feel free to ask for more.

Br. Gábor

Comment: Thank you Br. Gábor, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT use `getItemString()` for this purpose.  Use the `data` argument to the `itemChanged` event.

If the DW field contains the string "before", and your user types "after", `getItemString()` in the `itemChanged` event will return "before".  The DW column does not contain the data the user typed until AFTER the `itemChanged` event fires (and you didn't return a non-zero return code)

Comment: good point NoazDad.  This is right, checking values in the itemchanged event needs to be done correctly.  I would add, do not rely on itemchanged events for data integrity.  Typically you'd check data prior to update, many frameworks have a validate or (ue_validate) event and if the data is bad you can prevent update from happening.